# How i pass string from main activity to broadcast receiver with alarm manager?

Tags: android, android-intent

I create an application with alarm manager and broadcast receiver and i want pass string from main activity to public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver(i have alarm manager inside) and then to public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver for pass data to static function....In main activity save this variable from editbox with shared preferences.But i can not use shared preference inside receiver.How i can do this?

```
 public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  int theHour = intent.getIntExtra("AlarmHour", 0);  
  int theMinute= intent.getIntExtra("AlarmMin", 0); 

AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

i.putExtra("data","1");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, theHour);  // set user selection
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, theMinute); 
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

service.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    cal.getTimeInMillis(), pending);

}


public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);

 context.startService(service);

 String result = intent.getStringExtra("data");

 String msg=result;
 try {

    ArduBtTimer.sendData(msg);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: u have to add string value in pending intent and get that value from on recieve

Comment: How i can do this?Some code?

Comment: u already done with intents and recieve in reciever

Comment: i.putExtra("data", "1");

Comment: i.putExtra("data",yourstring);   and recieve with String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");

Comment: I have error create method getIntent()

Comment: u want only "1" value and u have no error for String result??

Comment: When i put String result=intent.getStringExtra(); no errors but no work...

Comment: I need to add the extras to the Intent before you pass it to the PendingIntent

Comment: print that value and see what happens?? or it shows null value

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 where u want to set value:
 i.putExtra("data",yourstring); 
 and for recieve: 
 String value = intent.getStringExtra("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should send the info you want to save using a BroadCastReceiver and save it with SP
there.

here is an example for sending info from receiver to activity:

1. Create an inner class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` in the activity you want to get your data to:

   ```
   private BroadcastReceiver ReceivefromService = new BroadcastReceiver(){
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
       {
           //get the data using the keys you entered at the service
           String IncomingSms=intent.getStringExtra("incomingSms");//
           String phoneNumber=intent.getStringExtra("incomingPhoneNumber");

       }
   };
   ```
2. Add this to `onPause()`:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       try {
           unregisterReceiver(ReceivefromService);
       } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
           if (e.getMessage().contains("Receiver not registered")) {
               Log.i("TAG","Tried to unregister the reciver when it's not registered");
           }
           else
           {
               throw e;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add this to `onResume()`:

   ```
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       filter.addAction("android.intent.action.SmsReceiver");
       registerReceiver(ReceivefromService, filter);
       //the first parameter is the name of the inner class we created.
   }
   ```
4. Create an intent inside the receiver/service that start the broadcast like this:

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.SmsReceiver").putExtra("incomingSms", message);
   i.putExtra("incomingPhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
   context.sendBroadcast(i);
   ```

hope it will help you out...